# Routing in MVC4 Application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-areas

I am in search of finding a best way to route users based upon their role in MVC4 application.

Basically I have 3 types of users in my application

1)Admin
2)Staff
3)Client

How can I achieve this?

```
admin/home (for each admin request it starts with admin/{controller}....)
staff/home  (for each staff request it starts with staff/{controller}....)
client/home  (for each client request it starts with client/{controller}....)
```

Thanks.

Comment: Similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8181284/mvc-role-based-routing

Comment: It looks like I have to use different Area in my application.Isn't it? If so, I m wondering if there is any other way to explicitly define routes instead of using Areas. But I don't have any idea how to do that if it is possible.

Comment: Well at some point you will have to authenticate the user. So another option would be in your login controller to then redirect them based on their roles.

Comment: Agreed! But at the same time I want to present different login view to admin/staff/client. And after they logged in, I want them to redirect to their specified route. For Example: If admin login it will redirect to the address like /admin/home

Comment: Than seems kind of odd, you don't know what type of visitor it is until you authenticate them. To accomplish different login views you would have to tell each user to specifically go to a URL (adim/login) to login instead of having a single point of entry and them routing to a landing page.

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely right. May be this one also looks odd to you as I am new working with MVC. Can I use single Login Controller for all three request (admin/login, staff/login, client/login)? And before authenticating a user I can check them by using which url he comes and logged him in based on the url and redirect to the their related route on landing page. OR I have to use Areas in application? What would be the best approach? To be honest I am very confused at this point and want to know better solution and suggestion. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

3) There is an attribute which you place upfront of your actions in your controller, so there you can list what kinda role is allowed for this particular action. You can also create your own filters.

Answer (score 0):

Ok here is what I suggest, make a new project and use the 'internet template'. Out of the box they set up a login page for you and this will give you an idea of how to set it up in your own application.

Based on the set up from above, you will need to edit the `AccountController` and add something like this to the Login Post Action.

```
 if (User.IsInRole("Admin"))
 {
     return RedirectToAction("Home", "AdminController");
 }
 if (User.IsInRole("Staff"))
 {
     return RedirectToAction("Home", "StaffController");
 }
 if (User.IsInRole("Client"))
 {
     return RedirectToAction("Home", "ClientController");
 }
```

Don't forget to add the `[Authorize(Roles = "RoleName")]` attribute to four controllers, or it won't matter if they are logged in or not.

Also, take a look at http://www.asp.net/mvc they have numerous resources for learning about asp.net mvc.

Comment: OK got it. But as I said I want the request url should be (admin/...). So, I have to make all actions in the AdminController? Can't I make more controllers? I guess, If I create separate controller then the request url will not be like as I wanted.

Comment: The way routing works out of the box is /{controller}/{action} so when you redirect to the AdminController the URL will be /Admin/Home. I really encourage you to go through the information on the asp.net web site all this is explained.