# Response is not Available in this context Global.asax

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, global-asax

I'm checking user is authorized already or not in global.asax if true then redirect to some route

```
if (false)
{
    HttpContext.Current.Response.RedirectToRoute("Login");
}
```

It throws exeption :

> Response is not available in this context

Comment: you should be using custom action filter

Comment: You shouldn't do any routing in the `global.asax`, what is it you are trying to achieve?

Comment: @CallumLinington  i have roles and when user with particular role (already authorized) makes request to my server to route to the right controller and action

Comment: Instead of writing anything in global.asax you should consider creating Authorize Filter.

Comment: @AkashKava rather than create your own, you should inherit from `AuthorizeAttribute` and override the appropriate methods.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it would be a better solution to make use of the [authentication tag](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/532aee0e(v=vs.100).aspx) in the `web.config`.

```
// or loginUrl="~/Account/LogOn" for example in an MVC application
<authentication mode="Windows">
   <forms 
      name=".ASPXAUTH" 
      loginUrl="login.aspx"       
      defaultUrl="default.aspx" 
      protection="All" 
      timeout="30" 
      path="/" 
      requireSSL="false" 
      slidingExpiration="true" 
      cookieless="UseDeviceProfile" domain="" 
      enableCrossAppRedirects="false">
      <credentials passwordFormat="SHA1" />
   </forms>
   <passport redirectUrl="internal" />
</authentication>
```

You can define a **loginUrl** where the user will be *redirected in case the user tries to access a ressource which requires authentication*.

**Update**

According to your given comment I think you may be looking for an authorization based routing. There is already an answer for that in this **SO Question** [*MVC role-based routing*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8181284/mvc-role-based-routing).

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, ASP.NET creates `HttpContext` object together with `HttpRequest` and `HttpResponse` objects. It happens before creation of the `HttpApplication` instance.

So it seems that `HttpContext.Current` just doesn't work at this stage.

Inside application event's handlers you can get the context throw the `sender`:

```
private void OnAuthorizeRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var application = (HttpApplication)sender;
    var context = (HttpContext)application.Context;
}
```

(`AuthorizeRequest` is a right place to redirect anonymous users, cause previous `AuthenticateRequest` *has authenticated* or *hasn't authenticated* the user already.)

See details [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc188942.aspx).

**It's important:** the neighbor answer is absolutely correct, and you should use `web.config` to make this thing. My answer about "how it works", and "how it could be done".