# Defining role-based default routing in .NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm surprised I haven't come across this before, but I'm attempting to find a way to redirect to the default route post-authentication based on a user's role.

To set up an example, let's say there are two roles, Admin and Tester.  An Admin's default route should be `admin/index` and the `AdminController` shouldn't be accessible to a Tester.  A Tester's default route should be `test/index` and the `TestController` shouldn't be accessible to Admin.

I looked into route constraints, but apparently they can only be used to determine whether a route is valid.  Then I attempted to try to call `RedirectToAction` after logging in, but that got a bit messy with return URLs and another reason that made it even more of a no-no which I can't remember at the moment.

I've landed on the following which I've implemented in my `BaseController`, but it's less than optimal to execute this on every controller action:

```
protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
{
    if (filterContext.Controller.GetType() == typeof(TestController) && 
        User.IsInRole("Admin"))
    {
        filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(new RouteValueDictionary(new { controller = "Admin", action = "Index" }));
    else if (filterContext.Controller.GetType() == typeof(AdminController) && 
        User.IsInRole("Tester"))
    {
        filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(new RouteValueDictionary(new { controller = "Test", action = "Index" }));
    } 
    else
    {
        filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(new RouteValueDictionary(new { controller = "Error", action = "AccessDenied" }));
    }
}
```

Is there a best practice for handling the default route based on user role?

Comment: you can use roles for a method in the controller. For example- User.IsInRole("Tester") public void methodname(){}  which implies, this method can only be accessible by the tester

Comment: Also take a look at this link - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8181284/mvc-role-based-routing

Comment: @HappyLee: Determining accessibility is not an/the issue.  Also, I had attempted to implement the solution you linked, but it didn't work and then I was told route constraints are only for verifying route validity.

Answer (score 0):

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;



[Authrorize]
public class AdminController : Controller{

 /* do your stuff in here. If your View is not actually a big difference from the tester view and you will only Hide some objects from the tester or viceversa, I suggest you use the same View but make a different methods inside the Controller. Actually you don't need to make AdminController and Tester Controller at all. */



}


// you can just do this in one Controller like

[Authorize(Roles="Admin")]
public ActionResult DetailsForAdmin(int id)
{
    var myRole = db.MyModelsAccounts.Find(id);
    return View("Admin", myRole);  //<- Admin returning View
}


[Authorize(Roles="Test")]
public ActionResult DetailsForTester

I think you get the Idea.
```

Comment: Not sure where the miscommunication occurred, but I know how to govern accessibility.