# Change route during runtime

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

Currently, we are working on HRIS (Human Resource Information System). We have different user types such as Admin, HR, Employee. But that user types are not static. We want to have different route for each user type.

e.g.

```
https://website/admin/{controller}/{id}
```

The route will depend on the user who logged-in in the system. Will read its user type.

May we know if there's a way to configure the route for each user type?

Comment: It should be possible I think depending on what exactly you are trying to accomplish. The question is not very clear as to exactly what you are trying to accomplish, but may I ask why you want to have the role in the route? if that is your method of determining the role of the currently logged in user that is not very secure.

Comment: We want to have separate route for each user type so we can determine what they are accessing. And since our system has many user type.

Comment: Have you managed to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution from my point of view would be:

1. You create a route (URL actually) that matches the pattern:

   ```
   https://website/admin/3
   ```

   that holds all the logic for this user - probably, invoking Model, asking for the respective user controller, e.g., **superadmin** and later on redirecting to...
2. Another URL matching

   ```
   https://website/admin/superadmin/3
   ```

   that now has both `controller = superadmin` and variable `id = 3`. It is not said, that the route should be different - you can implement the logic when the `controller` is either a `id` (integer) or `string` to keep the logic more centralized.
3. Just to mention:

   ```
   https://website/admin/3
   ```

   should be fine - you can process the request from the respective Controller without redirecting (see 1. point)

Answer (score 0):

This is very similar to the following question: [MVC role-based routing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8181284/mvc-role-based-routing)

Essentially you use areas, combined with a routing constraint.